# How to use multiple map values in ffmpeg-python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

How can I use multiple map values for different resolutions in ffmpeg-python?

```
    -map [v1out] -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 1900k -bufsize 3800k \
    -map [v2out] -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:0 900k -bufsize 1800k \
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give multiple map values in ffmpeg-python like:

```
ffmpeg.input('in.mp4').output(
...
map = [
    "[v1out] -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 1900k -bufsize 3800k",
    "[v2out] -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:0 900k -bufsize 1800k"
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
import ffmpeg

input_file = 'input.mp4'
output_file = 'output.mp4'
subtitles_file = 'subtitles.srt'
    
# Load the video/audio master.
input_ffmpeg = ffmpeg.input(input_file)

# Load the subtitle master.
input_ffmpeg_sub = ffmpeg.input(subtitles_file)

# Refer to the master audio, video and subtitles streams separately.
input_video = input_ffmpeg['v']
input_audio = input_ffmpeg['a']
input_subtitles = input_ffmpeg_sub['s']

output_ffmpeg = ffmpeg.output(
    input_video, input_audio, input_subtitles, output_file,
    vcodec='copy', acodec='copy', scodec='mov_text'
)

# If the destination file already exists, overwrite it.
output_ffmpeg = ffmpeg.overwrite_output(output_ffmpeg)

# Print the equivalent ffmpeg command we could run to perform the same action as above.
print(ffmpeg.compile(output_ffmpeg))

# Do it! transcode!
ffmpeg.run(output_ffmpeg)
```

This is the equivalent ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i subtitles.srt -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:s -acodec copy -vcodec copy -scodec mov_text output.mp4 -y
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i subtitles.srt -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:s -c:a copy -c:v copy -c:s mov_text output.mp4 -y
```

I hope it helps you, it worked for me.